# How to sort a list in python based on internal list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list as follow:

```
list1 = [['10', 'John', 'python'], ['1', 'Sara', 'java'], ['3','Tom', 'C']]
```

and as sorted result I expect following outpt:

```
3 Tom C
1 Sara Java
10 John python
```

in fact I want to sort it base on second parameter in internal list.
This code does not work:

```
sort1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[0][1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sort1 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

that `[1]` will be enough because it will iterate through the list and in each iteration x will be the inner list.

Comment: Please Add explanation.

Comment: It just needs to add **reverse=True** to the end to receive expected answer.